# instead of mouse click , use keypress

Tags: javascript, keypress, tampermonkey, keyup

hello i am currently experiencing a issue on my tampermonkey script on chrome where by i have to click my mouse on a search button to execute the script  , i am using keyup functions for other parts of the code and that works fine , however when it comes to this one i cant seem to get it to work , here is the section of code i would like to add a keypress to , i would like it to be when the "p" button is pressed it will execute and work thanks

```
 function attachfunctionToSearch(){
        if( $('.btn-standard.call-to-action').length>0){
            console.log('Search Button is Ready to click');
            $('.btn-standard.call-to-action').on("click",function(){
                var t = document.createElement("style");
            t.type = "text/css",
            t.innerText = "\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem {\n        height: 60px;\n    }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem .label {\n        font-size: 10px;\n  }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .auction {\n        margin-top: 0 !important;\n        font-size: 12px;\n        top: 4px;\n    }\n",
            document.head.appendChild(t)
                highlightValues();
            });
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                attachfunctionToSearch();
            }, 1000);

        }
    }
```

i have tried replacing the

```
.on("click", function(){
```

to something like

```
.keyup(function(p){
if (p.keycode == 80)
```

but it doesnt seem to work if anyone can help it would mean alot thanks

here is all the script if needed

```
// ==UserScript==
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
// @name         Fifa By Kappers
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.3
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       Kappers
// @match       https://www.ea.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/
// @grant        none
// @updateURL   https://github.com/sefbsdfb/fielkappers/tree/main/downloads/Fifa_By_Kappers.user.js
// @downloadURL https://github.com/sefbsdfb/fielkappers/tree/main/downloads/Fifa_By_Kappers.user.js

// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...

    let PlayerDataMap = new Map();
    function hightLightPlayer(){
        $.get( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sefbsdfb/fielkappers/main/Replace%20-%20Sheet1%20(3).csv", function( CSVdata) {
            var lines=CSVdata.split("\n");
            var headers=lines[0].split(",");

            for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
                if(lines[i] != ""){
                var currentline=lines[i].replaceAll('"' , "").split(",");
                    var name = currentline[0].normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").split(" ");
                    let key = name[name.length-1]+currentline[1];
                    let value = currentline[2].trim();
                    PlayerDataMap.set(key , value);
                }
            }
            console.log('loading player data....');
            if($('.icon-transfer').length>0){
                console.log('Transfers Button is Ready to click');
                $('.icon-transfer').on('mouseover' , function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        attachFunctionToTranfer();
                    }, 2000);
                });
            }else{
                setTimeout(function(){
                    hightLightPlayer();
                }, 2000);
            }

        });

    }
    hightLightPlayer();
    function attachFunctionToTranfer(){
        if($('.ut-tile-transfer-market').length>0){
            console.log('Transfers banner is Ready to click');
            $('.ut-tile-transfer-market').on("mouseover",function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    attachfunctionToSearch();
                }, 800);
            });
        }
        else{
            attachFunctionToTranfer();
        }
    }
    function attachfunctionToSearch(){
        if( $('.btn-standard.call-to-action').length>0){
            console.log('Search Button is Ready to click');
            $('.btn-standard.call-to-action').on("click",function(){
                var t = document.createElement("style");
            t.type = "text/css",
            t.innerText = "\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem {\n        height: 60px;\n    }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem .label {\n        font-size: 10px;\n  }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .auction {\n        margin-top: 0 !important;\n        font-size: 12px;\n        top: 4px;\n    }\n",
            document.head.appendChild(t)
                highlightValues();
            });
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                attachfunctionToSearch();
            }, 1000);

        }
    }
    function highlightValues(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('Getting Everything Ready');
            getPlayerDataFromSite();
        },1000);
    }

    function getPlayerDataFromSite(){
        for(var i=0;i<=19;i++){
            var name = $('.name:eq('+i+')').text();
            name = name.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
            var rating = $('.rating:eq('+i+')').text();
            var fullNAme = name.split(' ');
            var SitePlayerPrice = '';
            if($('.auction:eq('+i+')').children('div').eq(2).text().split(":")[1]!=undefined){
              SitePlayerPrice= $('.auction:eq('+i+')').children('div').eq(2).text().split(":")[1].replaceAll(",","");
            }
            var ExcelDataSheetPrice = PlayerDataMap.get(fullNAme[fullNAme.length-1]+""+rating);
            console.log('ExcelSheetPrice',fullNAme[fullNAme.length-1]+""+rating,"==>" , ExcelDataSheetPrice);
            console.log('SitePrice',name+""+rating+"==>" , SitePlayerPrice);
            if(ExcelDataSheetPrice!=undefined && parseInt(SitePlayerPrice)<=parseInt(ExcelDataSheetPrice*1.03)){
                $('.name:eq('+i+')').parent().css('background-color','orange');
            }
            if(ExcelDataSheetPrice!=undefined && parseInt(SitePlayerPrice)<=parseInt(ExcelDataSheetPrice)){
                $('.name:eq('+i+')').parent().css('background-color','green');
            }
            if(ExcelDataSheetPrice!=undefined && parseInt(SitePlayerPrice)<=parseInt(ExcelDataSheetPrice*0.97)){
                $('.name:eq('+i+')').parent().css('background-color','magenta');
            }
            if(ExcelDataSheetPrice!=undefined && parseInt(SitePlayerPrice)<=parseInt(ExcelDataSheetPrice*0.80)){
                $('.name:eq('+i+')').parent().css('background-color','red');
            }

        }
        $('.pagination.prev').keyup(function(e){
            if (e.keycode == 37)
            e.preventDefault();
            var t = document.createElement("style");
            t.type = "text/css",
            t.innerText = "\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem {\n        height: 60px;\n    }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem .label {\n        font-size: 10px;\n  }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .auction {\n        margin-top: 0 !important;\n        font-size: 12px;\n        top: 4px;\n    }\n",
            document.head.appendChild(t)
            setTimeout(function(){
                getPlayerDataFromSite();
            }, 500);
        });

        $('.pagination.next').keyup(function(e){
            if (e.keycode == 39)
            e.preventDefault();
            var t = document.createElement("style");
            t.type = "text/css",
            t.innerText = "\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem {\n        height: 60px;\n    }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem .label {\n        font-size: 10px;\n  }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .auction {\n        margin-top: 0 !important;\n        font-size: 12px;\n        top: 4px;\n    }\n",
            document.head.appendChild(t)
            setTimeout(function(){
                getPlayerDataFromSite();
            }, 500);
        });
    }








})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with:

```
.keyup(function(p){
if (p.keycode == 80)
```

But it should be:

```
.on("keyup", function(event){
  if (event.key == "p"){
     . . . .
  }
});
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$("textarea").on("keyup", function(event){
  if (event.key == "p"){
    console.log("p key pressed");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Click in here and press the "p" key</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just switch from "click" to "keypress" it will not work because you are adding the event to the element in question. As I understand it, you want this to act as a keyboard shortcut on your page. To do this, you must add the keypress event to the "document", thus making the whole document hear your event.

It can be implemented as follows:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function(event) {

  if(event.which === 80){ // 80 is equivalent to "p"
   // do stuf
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remember that this code snippet must be implemented and run as soon as the page is loaded, it should not be inside the click function for example.